# Questions coming in from Technical Communication

Tags: discussion

As previously discussed in [Let's migrate content from Technical Communication here](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1473/2533) and also [on their meta](https://techcomm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/68/148) (probably not available for much longer), we are currently receiving a large number of incoming migrations from Technical Communication before that site gets shut down.

Everyone please be patient while the front page floods. We should be back to something resembling our regular question rate soon.

Feel free to make any necessary adjustments to the incoming questions to make them better fits on Writing (while, of course, keeping post owner intention in mind, as always).

You'll see some new tags, including some "genre" tags, for tech writing, as discussed in [How can we improve our tech-writing tags?](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1476/how-can-we-improve-our-tech-writing-tags).  Tags are, as always, a work in progress.

Comment: And please show a warm welcome to our new users and help them find their way on our site.